# How to apply monospaced fonts to a label in iOS versions below 13?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the function UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 24.0, weight: .regular) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/3042484-monospacedsystemfontofsize?language=objc to apply a monospaced font to a label. It is working fine for iOS 13, but it crashes when I run the app in iOS 12. I read that this function is only available for iOS 13. Do you know how can I apply a monospaced font for devices running an iOS version below 13? Thanks!

Comment: eg. `UIFont(name: "Menlo", size: 24.0)`... ...

Answer (score 0):

hey Erich Flock you can use that code it will help you out. i'm also getting same issue but in different topic so it help for me.

```
 if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    return //code for ios 13
  } else {
    return // code for ios 12 or lower version
  }
```